# Rest Request to insert/update record in external system

Tags: rest-api

I have to integrate SFDC with an external system where I have to insert/update a custom object record. 
External system team is asking to send a REST request to update/insert the record.

I don't know how make REST request for whole record. It has more than 100 fields. Do i have put all of fields value in URL ???

Comment: you can send a rest request wit a json body with the fields  but it will depend on how the receiving end expects to get the request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would typically send a POST request, rather than a GET, to insert/update a record, so you could pass your 100+ fields as JSON or XML in the POST body. Check what the external system team is expecting to see!

Comment: Thanks metadaddy. Got it. I have to create send the record in json request to make insert/update external sys. . Can I serialize the object's record to make the Rest request body.

Comment: Yes - you can serialize a record with `JSON.serialize(myRecord)`, but that's only going to be helpful if the field names are identical. If they are different in the other system, create an Apex Class with fields to match what 'they' want, create an instance, copy in the data, then call `JSON.serialize` on that Apex Class instance.

Comment: Ok. It's a kind of wrapper class to match the field name and datatype with external system. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide some code sample for this task.
I have same issue.

Comment: There are lots of samples out there - check out [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) and [this blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/).